# SQL Server Access via Sqlcmd via IP address not working

Tags: sql-server

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2019, version 15.0.2000.5 on Windows 11, version 10.0.22621 Build 22621. After the standard installation, I can access the instance via PowerShell using:

```
sqlcmd -S "<machin-name>\SQLEXPRESS" -U sa -P <password>
```

I have also set up a docker version of MS SQL Server which I can access via:

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,1433 -U sa -P <password>
```

I would like to be able to do the same for the native installed version, but I'm unable to resolve `"<machin-name>\SQLEXPRESS"` outside of PowerShell or use localhost. I was told to rerun the installation and add a "Database Engine" which would resolve the endpoint issue, but I cannot find any documentation on this. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Do you mean you can't connect to the SQLExpress instance from a different host? Do you have the SQL Server browser and TCP/IP enabled?

Comment: *"but I'm unable to resolve "<machin-name>\SQLEXPRESS" outside of PowerShell or use localhost."* By "use localhost" do you mean you're doing something like `sqlcmd -S localhost`? That would try to connect to a default instance running on port 1433. `SQLEXPRESS` is a named instance and doesn't run on port 1433 (by default). As for your docker environment, you haven't told us what port you are forwarding to port 1433 on the container.

Comment: Thanks Thom. The docker version is exposing port 1433, so from wsl2 I was able to connect with the given sqlcmd with the arg, "-S 127.0.0.1,1433" You point out that I have a "named instance" and this is what I am trying to resolve with this question. I do not mind if it is a named instance if I can also connect via an IP address. However, if it must be either a named instance or have an IP access then it is the issue. I may have not realized that I was creating a "named instance" as I thought I was taking all the defaults. Is there a conversion path or do I have to perform a new installation?

Comment: So why can't you use `<IP Address>\SQLExpress`?

Comment: *"I may have not realized that I was creating a "named instance" as I thought I was taking all the defaults."* SQL Express is a named instance by default.

Comment: I believe that is the answer to this question!

Comment: To your prior question, why can't I use `<IP Address>\SQLExpress` it is because I need to use wsl2 and `sqlcmd` in particular for my development. All attempts to connect from wsl2 have failed as it cannot resolve "SQLExpress":
`~$ sqlcmd -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P <password>
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred...

Comment: `localhost`, within the container, will refer to the container not the host of the container; of course `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` will fail as it's not running within  the container.

Comment: From a networking point of view Docker containers are effectively a little Linux VM so `localhost` will always resolve to themselves. If you have a process in a Docker container trying to connect to the SQL Express instance running on the Docker host then `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` will never succeed because the container has neither that SQL Express instance itself nor does it have the SQL Browser service that's required to resolve the `SQLEXPRESS` instance name to the actual TCP port number that the instance would be listening on. Have you tried `host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS` yet?

Comment: I am in the process of reinstalling SQL Server as a non-named service, as the default in other words. This should allow me to access it via IP, port 1433. That at least is my expectation. I have not tried, "host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS" but that was when I was using a named service endpoint. I will update what I find with the "default" endpoint.